# Magento 2.3.2 default magento unit test failed

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.3.2 version and my php version is 7.2, 
i ran unit test command for default magento , 
the command is -
vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist

after running this command i'm getting this result -
Tests: 21867, Assertions: 61116, Errors: 3, Failures: 5, Skipped: 119, Incomplete: 43

If i see the details of this results its showing something like this-

There were 119 skipped tests:-

1) Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\SaveTest::testExecute with data set #0 (false, 7, 123)
Due to MAGETWO-48956

2)Magento\Framework\Lock\Test\Unit\Backend\ZookeeperTest::testConstructionWithPathException
Test was skipped because php extension Zookeeper is not installed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Can any body help me on my posted issue.

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. Could anyone, please help us with the solution to this issue.